# Azure Portal - Unable to Create a Signal R Service

Tags: azure, signalr, azureportal

I tried creating Signal R service with a Deployment failed message shown below.

> Deployment to resource group '' failed. Additional details
>   from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource
>   deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for
>   details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details

I can see the service created in my Signal List even after getting the above error while creating it.

However, in the overview tab I can see the below error.

### [image]

After clicking on the above error, I can see the code that says "Invalid RG"
Is there any problem with my RG?

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of azure SignalR itself, I try to create the service via portal and powershell, and get the same error.

I have opened a [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/260) in the Github, you could trace it for progress.

**Update**:

It works fine in the portal today, seems something wrong with it yesterday.

[image]